# Closed orientable 4-manifold with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2$ and non-zero cup product $H^1\times H^1\to H^2$

Tags: geometry, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I am looking for an example of a closed orientable 4-manifold $M$ with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2$ and non-zero cup product $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\times H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\to H^2(M;\Bbb Z_2)$.

A non-orientable example is $\Bbb RP^4$. An orientable example of dimension 3 is $\Bbb RP^3$.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{R}P^3 \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JimBelk Sorry, I edited the question: _closed_ manifold.

Comment: Take $S^1 \times S^3$. Are you sure this is the question you meant to ask?

Comment: Now posted at MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/209251/1916

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But $S^1\times S^3$ has a zero cup product $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\times H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\to H^2(M;\Bbb Z_2)=0$, doesn't it?

Comment: @Irina: that wasn't in your question when I read it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, I apologize: I clarified the question after your comment. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @Irina, **please** do not ask the same question here and on MO at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the squaring operation $H^1(-;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H^2(-;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ coincides with the Bockstein.  It follows your cohomological condition is equivalent to $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}_{(2)})=\mathbb{Z}/2$.  One example of such a manifold is the [Enriques surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriques_surface), which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and universal cover the K3 surface.  More generally, you can construct closed oriented 4-manifolds with any desired finitely presented fundamental group; see the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15411/finite-generated-group-realized-as-fundamental-group-of-manifolds), for instance.